# Pass state as prop to child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

As the title says, how can I pass state data to a new component. I have a parent class that loads some data from an IndexedDb.

I will pass the information of "image" as prop to my child component.

```
class Parent extends Component<Props> {

constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    // map state to json structure
    this.state = {
        data: {
          image: ''
          [...]
        };
}

public componentWillMount() {
    const dataProvider = new DataProvider(DataProvider.DBNAME);
    dataProvider.loadData('somedoc')
        .then((data: object) => this.setState({data}));
}

public render() {
    const {data}: any = this.stat
    return (<Child image={data.image} />);
}}
```

In my child Component I will use the prop to make a new request for retrieving the image. The problem is that the prop in the componentWillMount method is empty.

```
interface IImageProps {
image: string;
}

Class Child extends Component<IImageProps> {
constructor(props: IImageProps) {
    super(props);
}

public componentWillMount() {
    console.log("image", this.props.image); // <-- it's allways empty
    // do some async stuff
}

public render() {
    console.log("image", this.props.image); // <-- the image information is shown
}}
```

What did I miss, cause in the render methode I can use the prop? How do I pass the variables correctly?

Comment: Are you using React 16?

Comment: The project is build with React 16.4.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for helping. I solved my problem with the componentDidUpdate() method. As describe in the documentation https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/postrender_with_componentdidupdate.html

For now my final solution:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const imageName: string = this.props.imageName;
    const dataProvider = new DataProvider(DataProvider.DBNAME);

    dataProvider.loadImage('somedoc', imageName)
        .then((response: any) => {
            let {imageDataUrl}: any = this.state;
            if (imageDataUrl !== response) {
                imageDataUrl = response;
                this.setState({imageDataUrl});
            }
        })
        .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `loadData` function is asynchronous, `data.image` will be an empty string when the `Child` component is mounted.

You could e.g. wait with the rendering of the `Child` component until the request has finished.

**Example**

```
class Parent extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: {
        image: null
      }
    };
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    const dataProvider = new DataProvider(DataProvider.DBNAME);
    dataProvider
      .loadData("somedoc")
      .then((data: object) => this.setState({ data }));
  }

  public render() {
    const { data }: any = this.stat;

    if (data.image === null) {
      return null;
    }

    return <Child image={data.image} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're assuming that the image data isn't loaded by the time the parent renders the child component. I think he's more or less assuming he has the data in his parent and it won't pass to the child component. if he's using React 16 the async nature of the render method is more likely the issue, componentWillMount is no longer safe for things like this. There's no guarantee the component will have props or context at this point.

Comment: @JoshuaUnderwood `componentWillMount` is not the issue in this case, since `componentWillMount` only let you change state synchronously in earlier versions as well, not asynchronously.